Is there a way to increase the size of my MATERIAL Font.Image icons on my Toolbar?
Since our app is aimed at tablets and the desktop, I need to increase the back arrow and check mark on my toolbar. I cannot find a mention of increasing the size of FontImages, just for the title text. I was able to change the size of the floating button and the swipable button, but not the FontImages. Has anyone had success increasing the size of the icons?

You can, using Style from this answer

Also I would add that you don't want to increase size for tablets. Those aren't "bigger UI's". You need to focus on better usage of the environment. The UI looks small in the simulator because of density differences. On the device it would look great.

@ShaiAlmog does this mean that size 4 in the answer above will appear the same even in tablets & ipads? I haven't tested in tablets & ipads yet

It will appear as a similar size in millimeters/inches but not in pixels since device density is different. The goal in adapting an app to different form factors is not to increase the size of the widgets but to fit more information on the screen.
